# HTML number input doesn't let me select it

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal challenge to make an editable D&D character sheet in a webpage. Naturally, this involves a lot of number inputs, and I'm `transform: translate;`ing all of the number inputs into the places I want them on the page, however, one of the inputs ('AC' in the snippet below) doesn't let me edit the information in it when I hover my cursor over it.

It only briefly lets me change anything when I hover over the top-left corner of it

when I comment out its `float: left` and its `transform: translate` it ends up underneath the 'initiative' element. Would that have anything to do with it?

```css
.third-column {
  transform: translate(0px, 265px);
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

#ac {
  float: left;
  transform: translate(77px, -50px);
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#initiative {
  transform: translate(-25px, -48px);
  font-size: 40px;
}

#speed {
  transform: translate(133px, -107px);
  font-size: 40px;
}

.hit-points {
  display: block;
}

#max-hp {
  transform: translate(73px, -60px);
  width: 190px;
  height: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

#hp {
  transform: translate(8px, -50px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
}

#temp-hp {
  transform: translate(8px, -3px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
}

.hd {
  transform: translate(-70px, 45px);
}

#hit-type {}

#hit-dice {
  transform: translate(-13px, 10px);
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
}

.death-saves {
  transform: translate(133px, -9px);
}

.death-save {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.atk-spell {}

#attacks {
  transform: translate(40px, 73px);
}

#attacks tr {
  height: 30px;
}

.weaponName {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  width: 130px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.atkBonus {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.damageType {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 120px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.otherAtks {
  transform: translate(6px, 83px);
  resize: none;
  width: 358px;
  height: 225px;
  background: none;
  line-height: 23px;
  border: none;
}

.equipment {
  transform: translate(35px, 152px);
}

#mons {
  transform: translate(-6px, -10px);
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.money {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

#mons li {}

#equip {
  transform: translate(8px, -30px);
  float: left;
  resize: none;
  width: 256px;
  height: 342px;
  background: none;
  line-height: 23px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-column">

  <!-- Armor Class -->
  <input type="number" id="ac" value="0" name="armor-c">

  <!-- initiative -->
  <p id="initiative"></p>

  <!-- Speed -->
  <p id="speed">0ft</p>

  <!-- Hit Points -->
  <div class="hit-points">
    <input type="number" name="max-hp" value="0" id="max-hp">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="hp" value="0" id="hp">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="temp-hp" value="0" id="temp-hp">
  </div>

  <!-- Hit Dice -->
  <div class="hd">
    <p id="hit-type">1d8</p>
    <input type="number" id="hit-dice" value="1">
  </div>

  <!-- Death Saves -->
  <div class="death-saves">
    <input type="checkbox" name="success1" class="death-save">
    <input type="checkbox" name="success2" class="death-save">
    <input type="checkbox" name="success3" class="death-save" id="success3">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fail1" class="death-save">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fail2" class="death-save">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fail3" class="death-save" id="fail3">
  </div>

  <!-- Attacks -->
  <div class="atk-spell">
    <table id="attacks">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="weaponName" id="wn1" value=""></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="atkBonus" id="ab1" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="damageType" id="dt1" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="weaponName" id="wn2" value=""></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="atkBonus" id="ab2" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="damageType" id="dt2" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="weaponName" id="wn3" value=""></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="atkBonus" id="ab3" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="damageType" id="dt3" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <textarea name="name" class="otherAtks"></textarea>
  </div>

  <!-- Money and Equipment -->
  <div class="equipment">
    <ul id="mons">
      <li><input type="number" class="money" id="copper" value="0"></li>
      <li><input type="number" class="money" id="silver" value="0"></li>
      <li><input type="number" class="money" id="E" value="0"></li>
      <li><input type="number" class="money" id="gold" value="0"></li>
      <li><input type="number" class="money" id="plat" value="0"></li>
    </ul>
    <textarea id="equip"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and why doing this ? what the purpose of this *strange* layout ? you should understand CSS to create the layout needed and don't use transfrom like that to align your elements

Comment: I'm doing this project as a personal challenge. I'm creating an editable D&D character sheet, hence the odd layout.

You're not wrong about how little I know CSS though XD

Comment: there is no reason tu use transform ... transform is not meant to create layout and place element ... consider positioned element, margin, padding, grid, etc etc ... for me trying to fix such layout is useless, better trying to re-create it in a good way

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. thanks for the input though!